# How to get all unicode characters supported by fonts？

Tags: c#, unicode, fonts

I means, how to get ALL SUPPORTED CHARATCTERS by a font(Font class)?
That's the first question.
I have found the solution:

```
        var families = Fonts.GetFontFamilies(@"C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\Arial.TTF");
        foreach (var family in families)
        {
            var typefaces = family.GetTypefaces();
            foreach (Typeface typeface in typefaces)
            {
                GlyphTypeface glyph;
                typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyph);
                IDictionary<int, ushort> characterMap = glyph.CharacterToGlyphMap;

                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ushort> kvp in characterMap)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}:{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
                }

            }
        }
```

BUT,What's the charaterMap(that IDictionary) contains?
That's the second question.
Thanks.

Comment: If a font is not installed on a windows machine windows will choose automatically a similar font.  Similar does not mean all the character will display correctly.  You can only use a font that contain all the character you are using.

Answer (score 2):

GlyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap returns a dictionary with all entries from the font's 'cmap' table. That is the precisely the table that determines what Unicode characters are supported by the font. Each entry has a Unicode code point as the key and the default glyph ID for that character as the value.